# What is the difference between "users" and "active user" in firebase analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-analytics

In firebase analytics: If I (as a user) uses an app three time in a day, then will it be counted as three user ? or one user with three session ? Please answer.

Thanks
Vipin

Answer (score 1):

Active users reports count the number of **unique** users that were active in a given time period. So if a single user is active multiple times in a day, they'll count as a single active user.